# Conditional Formating not showing correct results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am having a problem while applying conditional formatting in MS Excel 2016.

I have two numeric columns `[P & Q]`. And want to highlight cells in column `P` where the value is greater than its corresponding cell in column `Q`. I have used the following formula.

```
=$P1 > $Q1
```

In conditional formatting. The formula would be applied on some 1500 rows in column `P`. However I am getting wrong results as well as correct ones. I have attached an image of some results. Need help.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an exact screenshot of your conditional formatting, as I've tried and can' replicate the error

Comment: [As you can see here, it's working fine for the same results you have posted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrdim.png)

Comment: [![Here is the Complete screenshot of what in have done in conditional formatting][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fgP0S.jpg

Comment: Your formula is incorrect, I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: Mr. Draken after applying formula your way i got correct results. But still don't understand why my formula did not work? Thanks for sharing your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used conditional formatting incorrectly, it doesn't quite work the same as doing a standard excel formula.

For the results needed, you need to do something similar as below:

[image]

Where your rule should be:

```
Cell value > $Q1
```

Don't worry that we haven't referenced the other cells in Q, excel is clever enough to know to apply the rule down the column and change the row number where applicable.

You then need to apply it to the column:

```
=$P:$P
```

This will give you the result that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same

```
=$A2 > $B2
```

for 40 sample columns, and found the result correct.

[image: Proof of correct result]

Comment: Your result may be correct my dear. But it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the change the formula to

```
=$P2>$Q2
```

It will work. Make sure to give the reference of the “first cell to be evaluated” in the formula.

In your case it is the cell in 2nd row not the first row.